# Error: DDL statements are not allowed in transactions while running setup:upgrade. Running Data Patch

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

Magento 2.3.1

After making the data patch at the following location:

`vendor/ModuleName/Setup/Patch/Data/AddMyColumnPatch.php`

(Code given below for `AddMyColumnPatch.php`)

When I run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` to get this patch installed I get following error at cli:

> DDL statements are not allowed in transactions

I have used the following file as reference to add a column to my table using data patch:

`vendor/magento/module-quote/Setup/Patch/Data/InstallEntityTypes.php`

Follow lines from 47 to 65.

My `AddMyColumnPatch.php` code is:

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup\Patch\Data;


use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 */
class AddressSuburbPatch implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    /**
     * Attribute Code of the Custom Attribute
     */
    const CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_CODE = 'my_column';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory
     */
    private $quoteSetupFactory;


    /**
     * @var Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory
     */
    private $salesSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory,
        SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory,    
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {

        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;          
        $this->quoteSetupFactory = $quoteSetupFactory;
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;            
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();


        $this->logger->debug('DDL Statements error');

        $quoteSetup = $this->quoteSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $quoteSetup->addAttribute('quote_address', self::CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_CODE, ['type' => 'text']);

        $salesSetup = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $salesSetup->addAttribute('order_address', self::CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_CODE, ['type' => 'text']);

        $this->logger->debug('Script working');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {

        return [

        ];
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {

        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through declarative schema docs again and referencing core Magento code for quote module and PayPal module I have figured out that if you want to add a field into an existing table in Magento >=2.3 you should use configure declarative schema for that. Read more:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

So create a `db_schema.xml` file under `Vendor/ModuleName/etc`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="quote_address" resource="checkout" comment="Sales Flat Quote Address">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="suburb" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Suburb for Quote Address" />
    </table>
    <table name="sales_order_address" resource="sales" comment="Sales Flat Order Address">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="mycolumn" nullable="true" length="255" comment="mycolumn for Sales Order Address" />
    </table>
</schema>
```

Then generate whitelist for your db_schema as follows:

```sh
bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_ModuleName
```

Run again and your column will be added to `quote_address` and `order_sales_address` tables.

```sh
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

However, further investigation revealed that there is no need of making data patch for adding columns in flat tables `quote_address` and `sales_order_address`. Only declaring columns in `db_schema.xml` will do the job.